# How to get the feature names in a different pipeline in sklearn in python

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, classification, pipeline

I am using the following code ([source](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/compose/plot_feature_union.html#sphx-glr-auto-examples-compose-plot-feature-union-py)) to concatenate multiple feature extraction methods.

```
from sklearn.pipeline import Pipeline, FeatureUnion
from sklearn.model_selection import GridSearchCV
from sklearn.svm import SVC
from sklearn.datasets import load_iris
from sklearn.decomposition import PCA
from sklearn.feature_selection import SelectKBest

iris = load_iris()

X, y = iris.data, iris.target

pca = PCA(n_components=2)
selection = SelectKBest(k=1)

# Build estimator from PCA and Univariate selection:
combined_features = FeatureUnion([("pca", pca), ("univ_select", selection)])

# Use combined features to transform dataset:
X_features = combined_features.fit(X, y).transform(X)
print("Combined space has", X_features.shape[1], "features")

svm = SVC(kernel="linear")

# Do grid search over k, n_components and C:
pipeline = Pipeline([("features", combined_features), ("svm", svm)])

param_grid = dict(features__pca__n_components=[1, 2, 3],
                  features__univ_select__k=[1, 2],
                  svm__C=[0.1, 1, 10])

grid_search = GridSearchCV(pipeline, param_grid=param_grid, cv=5, verbose=10)
grid_search.fit(X, y)
print(grid_search.best_estimator_)
```

I want to get the names of the selected features from the above code.

For that, I used, `grid_search.best_estimator_.support_`. However, this returned an error saying:

```
AttributeError: 'Pipeline' object has no attribute 'support_'
```

Is there a way to get the **selected feature names** as shown in the above code in sklearn in python?

I am happy to provide more details if needed.

Comment: It's possibly duplicate of the following SO https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36829875/how-to-get-feature-names-from-output-of-gridsearchcv

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is my approach to know the final features, used by the `best_estimator_`

```
>>> features = grid_search.best_estimator_.named_steps['features']

# number of components chosen from pca
>>> pca=features.transformer_list[0][1]

>>> pca.n_components
3

# features chosen by selectKbest
>>> select_k_best=features.transformer_list[1][1]

>>> select_k_best.get_support()
array([False, False,  True, False])
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. Please let me know if you know an answer for this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55671530/why-do-i-get-different-values-with-pipline-and-without-pipline-in-sklearn-in-pyt Thank you very much :)